# Как отправить POST-запрос (multipart/form-data)?

Tags: android

Задача: "Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, сформировав POST-запрос с полем photo. Это поле должно содержать изображение в формате multipart/form-data".

В интернете много информации, которая уже устарела. Помогите отправить фото и получить ответ.

Comment: Как это отправить картинку на сервер? Помоему можно передавать только текст...

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что информация устарела? Решения с `HttpURLConnection` те же самые, а, например, решение с `Retrofit 2` по первой же ссылке в гугле https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: @Flippy Что значит только текст? Передавать можно любые наборы байт, а наборы байт это любая информация в принципе. Текстовая строка это последовательность байт и не более, как и файл.